# Disabled key for bento combobox in angular 15

Tags: html, disable, angular15

Disabled key for bento combobox in angular , how it can be work for this in angular 15

```
 <div class="form-group">
        <label for="areaoflaw">{{'AREA_OF_LAW'| translate}}</label>
        <bento-combobox
          id="areaOflaw"
          [itemsObservable]="areaOfLawDataStream"
          [options]="cmbItemText"
          formControlName="areaOfLaw"
          [rowTemplate]="IComboboxTemplate">
        </bento-combobox>
        <div class="CustomErrorMessage" *ngFor="let item of matter.controls['areaOfLaw'].errors | keyvalue">
          <span class="Section-detailsError">{{validationMessages.areaOfLaw[item.key] || 'Error not handled, conatct ProLaw support '}}</span>``
        </div>
      </div>
```